# The team who ( has scored /scores ) more goals wins. - tense problem

Tags: tense

> Basketball is a sport played by 2 teams and each team has 5 players. The objective is to shoot a ball through a hoop. The team who ( has scored /scores ) more goals wins.

Even though we are not talking about an incident that happened in the past, we need to show which action is preceded by which action in one sentence, which has 2 verbs. That's why I think ***has scored or scored*** is right. Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not always necessary to explicitly state which action comes first, using different verb tenses - only when it is (or might be) crucial (or helpful) to the understanding of the sentence. Even if the person reading this sentence is not familiar with basketball, almost everyone understands that 'scoring goals' comes before 'winning', especially if you have those ideas and words in that order in the sentence.